# Printing AMCharts graphs on IE8

Tags: java, graph, internet-explorer-8, amcharts

I'm having a problem printing line graphs from [AMCharts](http://amcharts.com).
On my page, the chart is right, but when I try to print it, some spaces are blank.
For example, this image shows how I see the image on my page:

[image]

When I try to print it (CTRL + P), some spaces are blank. Look this image:

[image]

The problem happens only with IE8 or lower.
In IE9 and IE10 this problem happens when I put in compatibility mode.
In other browsers it works OK.

I need it working in IE8. We have some terminal servers running Windows Server 2003 and can not update the version of IE.
Using another browser is not possible either, because we need multisession and only IE provides this option. We plan to upgrade our servers to a new version of Windows, but it will require some time, and I'm looking for a quick fix.

From what I researched, the amCharts builds the graphics using SVG.
However, in IE8 (or IE9~IE10 using compatibility mode) it uses VML.

Is there any way to make it work with IE8?
Or convert the VML code generated to an Image using Java (language used in the system)?
I researched but dont find anything that can help me.
Is there anything I can do to make it work properly in IE8?